# R: How to best import infix operators like %>% into my package?

Tags: r, import, package, pipe

I am making an R-Package and I'm struggling with the import of infix functions like `%>%`, `:=` or `%dopar%`.

In the `DESCRIPTION`-file I use the `Imports: <otherPackage>` (e.g. `Imports: doParallel`) notion. Within the code I use the `package::function()` (e.g. `dplyr::mutate()`) notion, which seems to work (`R CMD check` is pleased) but how do I import infix functions?

The `@importFrom` (e.g `#' @importFrom magrittr %>%`) roxygen way seems to work for `%>%`, `:=` and `%dopar%`. But since it is copied over into the `NAMSEPACE`-file, adding the `@importFrom` to one function solves the problem package-wide, which seems rather "hacky".

What is the best practice to import such functions into my package?

Comment: The dot is not an operator, it's a symbol with special significance for `magrittr`, so it cannot be imported.

Comment: You are right, I changed the question to make it more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a single best practice in this case.
Using `@importFrom` to update the `NAMESPACE` file is indeed to be a package-wide directive,
but I've never come across a package that had problems with that,
or reasons to avoid it.
You can annotate several functions with the same `@importFrom` directive if you like,
denoting which functions use which imports,
and it won't cause any conflicts;
it's entirely up to you though,
a single one would suffice.
Using `@import` *might* be frowned upon,
but I think it really depends on which package you import.

From your question I gather you use `::` explicitly
(which I would personally say is good practice),
and then you don't even need to alter the `NAMESPACE`.
For most cases that would be just fine,
though there can be very special cases that usually need to be considered individually.
These special cases, at least in my experience, are usually related with S4 generics.

Take for instance the `base::rowSums` function:
it is *not* a generic function in `base`,
but if the `Matrix` package is attached,
`rowSums` is "transformed" into an S4 generic,
but the generic is *not* in the base package.
Why that's the case is beyond the scope of this answer
(see `?Methods_for_Nongenerics` for more information),
but it means that if your package uses the notation `base::rowSums`,
it would *not* dispatch to methods from `Matrix`.
The only way to support both cases
(i.e. when `Matrix` is not used by the user and when it is)
would be to use `rowSums` without `base::`.

Now, regarding infix operators,
if you wanted to use `::`,
you'd need something like  `` base::`%in%`("a", c("a", "b")) ``,
which essentially entails using it as a function and losing the infix syntax,
something you probably don't want.

So unless you have very specific reasons to avoid one or the other,
just use whatever notation you prefer.
I'd personally stick to `::` as much as possible,
but would never use it for infix operators.