# How to import operators from the patchwork package into my own package in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58094886/r-how-to-best-import-infix-operators-like-into-my-package), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211727/how-do-i-import-when-writing-an-r-package), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61116434/how-to-import-an-operator-from-matrix-in-a-package-in-r). However, they don't exactly solve the issue Im having.

Essentially, I am creating a package that has a function that creates a bar plot and then attaches other plots to the y-axis (a simple version of which is shown in the code below).

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(vals = c(10, 5, 18),
                 name = c("A", "B", "C"))
bp <- df |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = name, y = vals), stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) 

# create plots to use as x-axis --------------------------------------------

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = vals, y = vals)) + geom_point() + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) 

p3 <- p2 <- p1

# turn into list of plots
myList <- list(p1, p2, p3)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# attach plots to axis

width <- .9 # Default width of bars
p_axis <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_blank(aes(y = name)) +
  purrr::map2(myList, seq_along(myList), ~ annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(.x), ymin = .y - width / 2, ymax = .y + width / 2)) +
  theme_void() 

library(patchwork)
p_axis | bp
```

In the last line I am using the `|` operator from `patchwork` package. However, I'm not sure how I can explicitly import that operator into my own package. In my `roxygen` documentation, I tried `@importFrom patchwork "%|%"`... but when I run `devtools:document()` it says:

> Warning message:
> object ‘|’ is not exported by 'namespace:patchwork'

I have tried various combinations like `@importFrom patchwork "|"`, `@importFrom patchwork %|%`, etc., but all yield the same result.

Investigating it further it seems like the `|` operator may be an internal function in `patchwork`. For example, you can find it via `?patchwork:::|.ggplot`. So, since it's using the syntax `patchwork:::`, that means it's not exported, right!?

So is there a way to import that operator or is my only option to just import the full package (i.e., `@import patchwork`).

FYI: I have tried other methods that dont use the `patchwork` package, but my actual function is a bit more complicated and `patchwork` is the only one that seems to work well for me, so I kind of have to use it.

Comment: It's an S3 method, so it is `"|.ggplot"`. I would try `@importFrom patchwork "|.ggplot"`.

Comment: It will be difficult to import only the functions you need from patchwork, since the mechanisms that allow the syntax to work are mostly unexported.

Comment: It might be better to take advantage of ggplot's new guide system if you want a custom axis.

Comment: @GregorThomas, I still get the same warning from `devtools::document` using your suggestion.

Comment: @AllanCameron I have slight changed the code in the question (I added `coord_flip()`). What I am trying to do is essentially attach the plots to each tick mark on the axis of the barplot. I had a lot of difficulty trying to get the attached plots to align with the ticks and `patchwork` seemed to be a fix for it. Im not sure how I would use ggplots new guide system to achieve such a thing. Do you know of any documents or examples anywhere that I could check out?

Comment: I don't know of anything that's online yet that gives a how-to on guide creation other than [this](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/extending-ggplot2.html#creating-new-guides). It would be a really useful Q&A for this site, though I don't think it would be right to post as an answer to this question.